# Are the data structures for networkx appropriate for numerical schemes with adjacency dependence?

Tags: python, algorithm, graph, networkx

I want to do some calculations on a graph where each link and node has some state variables that are updated (from one time step to another) by considering the states of all connected elements in the previous time step.
In pseudocode this would be something like:

```
for nodes in graph:
    state(node,t+1)=f(state(node(t)),states(links(node,t)))
for links in graph:
    state(link,t+1)=f(state(start_node(link,t),end_node(link,t)))
```

with f being some function. Are the data structures in networkx appropriate for something like this or would an implementation be very inefficient? I want to do this with graphs that have up to 50000 edges.
A google search came up empty, any hints would be appreciated.

Comment: It may depend on what you're trying to do, but I routinely simulate epidemics on million node networks.  Can you say a bit more what you have in mind?

Comment: @Joel It's a traffic simulation; we track the passage of individual vehicles throughout the network by updating cumulative numbers at the beginning and end of links. Node models determine how many vehicles transition from one link to another, but that problem is not trivial  and needs some iterations until the solution algorithm finds a consistent solution. The epidemics example makes me hopeful that it could work though